# Can't access prop in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props

I'm getting myself confused with React here (total newbie). I have a simple component that fetches some data that always returns `{"score":100}`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Graph from "./Graph.js";

const UsingFetch = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState({"score": null}); // initially set score to null

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("https://myapi.com/id=1")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setResults(data); // update results with integer score
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  console.log(results)
  return (
    <div>
      <Graph results={results.score}></Graph>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UsingFetch;
```

My `Graph.js` looks like the following:

```
import { React } from 'react'

export default function Graph({results}) {
  console.log(results)
  return (
      <div>
          <h1>{results}</h1>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Why doesn't the score render on the page? I've confirmed that the data returns correctly, I just can't seem to access it right.

Here's the console output:

[image]

Comment: `result` -> `results`...

Comment: Apologies, typo. I fixed this and it still doesn't render.

Comment: are you sure `data` is the right shape (has a `score` property)?

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken? Have you logged the value of `results` in both components? What do they show?

Comment: Re debugging you might think about naming, with them both name `results` the assumption is they reference the same object, perhaps pass `score` to graph instead. `<Graph score={results.score} />`

Comment: So there's your answer. `results` is an array, not an object

Comment: I've added `console.log(results)` to both components. `score` is fetched as expected

Comment: @BrianThompson is there a way to make it an object instead? It'll never return an array.

Comment: No it's not, it's in an array, so you would need to `setResults(data[0])` if you want to maintain it as an object.

Comment: Solved it, thanks everyone! That was confusing me for way too long.

Comment: @flowermia apparently it does... Based on the code you provided, your API does return an array

Answer (score 0):

Results is an array.

```
<h1>{results.map((result) => (result.score)}</h1>
```